# Collapse categorical variable with numerous levels in GLM output

Tags: r

I am running a glm on a large dataset. Individual is a variable in this dataset and I have data from over 50 individuals. When I input `individual` into the glm, I end up with an output that is basically unusable.

```
gid1<- glm(rpm~sex+individual+age.days+season+location+SR+adult.pop+
             swelling+feeding.+locomotion.+ season:sex+location:sex, 
             family=Gamma (link="identity"), data=data)

summary(gid1)


Call:
glm(formula = rpm ~ sex + individual + age.days + season + 
    location + SR + adult.pop + swelling + feeding. + locomotion. + 
    season:sex + location:sex, family = Gamma(link = "identity"), 
    data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.43104  -0.11540  -0.03982   0.06615   1.82259  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            1.071e+00  5.659e-02  18.926  < 2e-16 ***
sexM                   1.585e-01  6.833e-02   2.320  0.02036 *  
individualAndre       -3.782e-02  5.810e-02  -0.651  0.51512    
individualBessie      -1.446e-01  7.279e-02  -1.986  0.04709 *  
individualBenjamin    -5.573e-03  5.919e-02  -0.094  0.92499    
individualBobo        -5.492e-03  4.689e-02  -0.117  0.90676    
individualBritney     -6.405e-03  4.408e-02  -0.145  0.88448    
individualCase        -1.213e-01  5.730e-02  -2.118  0.03423 *  
individualChilli      -1.065e-03  7.036e-02  -0.015  0.98793    
individualCinderella  -1.666e-01  5.575e-02  -2.989  0.00281 ** 
individualCrumble     -1.411e-02  6.435e-02  -0.219  0.82638    
individualDaniel       1.475e-01  5.686e-02   2.594  0.00951 ** 
individualDobby       -1.281e-01  5.516e-02  -2.323  0.02023 *  
individualDomino      -9.294e-02  4.452e-02  -2.087  0.03689 *  
individualDotty       -5.428e-02  4.936e-02  -1.100  0.27157    
individualFlip         1.753e-02  4.340e-02   0.404  0.68623    
individualFlop        -4.963e-02  4.363e-02  -1.138  0.25533    
individualForrest      7.738e-03  6.013e-02   0.129  0.89761    
individualForrest      1.959e-01  7.402e-02   2.647  0.00815 ** 
individualGemma        1.299e-01  6.021e-02   2.158  0.03099 *  
individualGeorgia     -7.884e-02  4.412e-02  -1.787  0.07401 .  
individualGravy        2.360e-02  6.074e-02   0.389  0.69763    
individualHoudini     -8.201e-02  4.921e-02  -1.666  0.09568 .  
individualJackie Chan -1.013e-02  4.332e-02  -0.234  0.81506    
individualJago         3.024e-02  4.348e-02   0.695  0.48687    
individualJessie      -4.516e-02  4.493e-02  -1.005  0.31486    
individualK-fed       -7.511e-02  6.576e-02  -1.142  0.25340    
individualKinky Tail   2.675e-02  5.759e-02   0.464  0.64232    
individualLefteye      2.614e-02  4.617e-02   0.566  0.57129    
individualLemon Slice  1.764e-01  5.747e-02   3.070  0.00215 ** 
individualLil' Mo     -9.632e-04  4.556e-02  -0.021  0.98313    
individualLisa        -2.543e-02  4.508e-02  -0.564  0.57272    
individualMaddox      -5.984e-03  5.952e-02  -0.101  0.91992    
individualMarshy      -2.724e-03  4.561e-02  -0.060  0.95238    
individualMiss Price  -4.522e-02  4.695e-02  -0.963  0.33552    
individualMystery      3.452e-02  4.701e-02   0.734  0.46271    
individualNak         -8.345e-02  5.658e-02  -1.475  0.14033    
individualNik         -1.219e-02  4.454e-02  -0.274  0.78431    
individualPimpernel   -6.083e-02  4.976e-02  -1.223  0.22153    
individualPlaydoh      2.499e-02  4.573e-02   0.547  0.58470    
individualPreston     -1.083e-01  4.856e-02  -2.230  0.02577 *  
individualPumpkin      8.218e-02  4.438e-02   1.852  0.06409 .  
individualScarlett    -8.742e-02  4.451e-02  -1.964  0.04957 *  
individualScoops      -1.343e-02  4.529e-02  -0.297  0.76675    
individualScrubs      -8.204e-02  5.636e-02  -1.456  0.14553    
individualSomalia     -1.702e-02  5.724e-02  -0.297  0.76618    
individualStroppy      2.732e-02  5.854e-02   0.467  0.64075    
individualSweetpea    -2.512e-02  6.071e-02  -0.414  0.67909    
individualTetley              NA         NA      NA       NA    
individualUncle B      3.246e-01  7.809e-02   4.157 3.27e-05 ***
individualWoody       -4.131e-02  5.662e-02  -0.730  0.46563    
age.days              -1.301e-05  4.643e-06  -2.802  0.00510 ** 
seasonautumn           5.327e-02  8.720e-03   6.109 1.07e-09 ***
seasonsummer           1.447e-02  8.234e-03   1.758  0.07882 .  
locationrock          -1.685e-02  9.594e-03  -1.756  0.07906 .  
SR                     6.310e-01  6.895e-02   9.151  < 2e-16 ***
adult.pop              3.942e-03  1.683e-03   2.342  0.01922 *  
swelling               2.923e-03  1.545e-03   1.892  0.05857 .  
feeding.              -1.791e-01  1.376e-02 -13.015  < 2e-16 ***
locomotion.           -1.542e-01  1.803e-02  -8.554  < 2e-16 ***
sexM:seasonautumn      3.809e-02  1.688e-02   2.256  0.02411 *  
sexM:seasonsummer     -1.739e-03  1.569e-02  -0.111  0.91173    
sexM:locationrock     -1.043e-01  1.331e-02  -7.837 5.48e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.03300723)

    Null deviance: 211.28  on 5741  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 157.68  on 5679  degrees of freedom
  (30 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: -1929

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I am looking for a code which would allow me to collapse the output of the glm so I get a single estimate, st. error, t-value, and p-value which summarizes the relationship between `individual` and my output variable.

In the past I have used the `drop1` function to do this, but it appears that the drop1 function no longer produces these values.

Is what I'm looking to do possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget the `test=` argument of `drop1`? `g1 <- glm(mpg ~qsec + factor(gear), data = mtcars); drop1(g1, test = "F")` (use `test="Chisq"` for a likelihood ratio test).  PS you might want to consider treating individual as a random effect in a generalized linear *mixed* model ... ?